# getting "ActionView::MissingTemplate" while rendering a simple json head response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In one of my controllers, I have this code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html{ redirect_to :me, :flash => {:error => t('quest_histories.misc.bad_request')}} and return
  format.json{ head :method_not_allowed } and return
end
```

BUT, when a json request comes, i get this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template quest_histories/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
* "/var/www/PMAC_RoR/app/views"
```

This really confuses me, because I have similar code in many other controllers and it's actually working... the controller just have to respond with a html header, it shouldn't need a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "and return" remove those, and put the return after the whole respond_to block.

Comment: already did, but forgot to write the answer here. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this:

```
render :nothing => true
```

Comment: instead of "head :method_not_allowed" ?

Comment: like "{ render :nothing => true, :status => :method_not_allowed }"

Comment: `render nothing: true, status: :method_not_allowed` is the same as `head :method_not_allowed` (head is just more explicit), so it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html{ redirect_to :me, :flash => {:error => t('quest_histories.misc.bad_request')}} and return
  format.json  { render :nothing => :true, :status => :no_content }
end
```

Comment: isn't that the same of "head :no_content" ?

Comment: I dont know but you can check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head

Comment: may be you can change `:status` parameter to `:method_not_allowed` or `:bad_request`.